# Resonance Mixer Master does not behave as regular Master mixer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resonance-audio

So I have a scene with audio objects plus a virtual 9.1 array. I have assigned the audio objects and the virtual array to two different mixer groups as I want to control the balance between the two layers. The mixer groups are themselves child of the Resonance Master Mixer as indicated by the developer guide https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/unity/developer-guide

My problem is that once the scene is played, I lose any control over the volumes of the two child-mixers, seems like the audio material passes to the Resonance Mixer directly and becomes unresponsive to slider controls and mute buttons.

Is this normal or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior, i.e., submixing features via Unity audio mixers are currently not supported by the Resonance Audio renderer plugin in Unity.

Please refer to [the corresponding issue on GitHub](https://github.com/resonance-audio/resonance-audio-unity-sdk/issues/19) for further details and updates respectively.